# C# Exception when accessing https URL via HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, https

I have following code  :

```
 private string GetDataFromWeb(string url)
        {
            /*this taken according to other posts here 
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) //exception occurs here 
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished read");
                return result;
            }

        }
```

When calling the function on some https site ( for example https://api.stackexchange.com)
Following exeption occurs on line where GetResponse called:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I tried also as recommemded in other posts to bypass ssl check by following code ( calling on start of the app )

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AlwaysGoodCertificate);`..
where

```
static bool AlwaysGoodCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

But still the exeption occurs

Running on Windows 7 , .net 4.5
Is there something wrong in the code above ?
When accessing same site via Chrome or via Nodejs app ( usinh fetch ) - request succeeded
Thanks in advance

Comment: In an updated Windows 7 (Service Pack 1 + all security updates available until end-of-life), the code you posted (even though you should remove all protocols except `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`), doesn't generate exceptions. You should also remove `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;`: your code clearly is not handling that, but it's another matter -- Overriding `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` doesn't *bypass SSL check*, it allows to ignore failed Server Certificates validations (to use with care).

Comment: Update the System, install .Net 4.8. You may lack the required Cipher Suites -- Note that in an updated System, the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` default value is the same as Windows 8+, `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault`, where the *default* should be `TLS12`, with the last Cipher Suites installed with the updates. Not the latest Cipher Suites, though. Some Sites that use *stricter security*, may only allows the most recent Cipher Suites, which are not included in Windows 7 by standard means (and never will be). WebBrowsers install and handle their own Cipher Suites.